# Is this possible to solve this definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, gaussian-integral

Is it possible to solve
$$
\int_c^d e^{-ax-bx^2} dx
$$
for $a$ and $b$ positive real numbers, and $c$ and $d$ real numbers?

I know it's possible when the bounds are infinity, but what about this case?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Although this may be a more unorthodox approach, the best way to solve this might be using a summation to represent the Gaussian integral.

Comment: You can change variables, just by completing the square, to get to $\int_p^q \; e^{-t^2} \; dt \;$ and then look up using some implementation of the error function. No "closed form"

Comment: @supersmarty1234, if I had a summation, what would I do with it? My goal is to get rid of the integral (or the summation)

Comment: @Ségo, Unfortunately, once transforming your integral into the error function, there's no true (that I know of) closed form of the error function. 
 However, there are many methods with various levels of accuracy that will represent the error function.  These in turn can be calculated as an integral with real $c$ and $d$.  Here's one link to a paper you might be interested in http://eprints.lancs.ac.uk/596/2/7BF32BA0.pdf, and there's also a wikipedia page here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function.

Comment: @Ségo Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a basic knowledge of special functions, in particular the Error Function, we can easily find out that:

$$\int e^{-ax - bx^2}\ \text{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{a^2}{4 b}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{a+2 b x}{2 \sqrt{b}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{b}}$$

Now you can fix the extrema as you like.

**Special values**

$$\text{erf}(0) = 0$$

$$\text{erf}(+\infty) = +1$$

$$\text{erf}(-\infty) = -1$$

More on Error Function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $u$ such that $2bu=a$ then

$$(bx+u)^2=bx^2+2bux+u^2$$

and

$$\int_c^d e^{-ax-bx^2} dx=e^{u^2}\int_c^d e^{-(bx+u)^2} dx$$

then set $bx+u=y$ and use [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).